# how to find minimum distance from a point to a graph using Mathematica?

Tags: calculus, optimization, mathematica

Find the point on the graph of $y= x^{3/2}$ that is closest to the point $(4, 0)$.

This is an optimization problem. I used the distance formula.

$d=\sqrt{(4-x)^2+(0-x^{3/2})^2}$

$d^2=16-8x+x^2+x^3$

Then I took the derivative of $d^2$ (after squaring both sides)

$(d^2)'=3x^2 +2x-8$

$0=(3x-4)(x+2)$

$x=\frac43$, $x=-2$

For the minimum distance, $x=\frac43$, so $y= \frac8{3\sqrt3}$

I want to be able to check my work using Mathematica. Does anyone know how I can do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's better to ask on a Mathematica-specific forum.

Comment: What specific step do you want to check?

Comment: @SuzuHirose ok I will post it there.

Comment: @GregMartin I want to see my answer to be sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with solution by incantation, you can do the following:

```
f = Function[x, x^(3/2.)] (* your function *)
{px, py} = {4, 0}  (* your point *)
d2 = (px - x)^2 + (py - f[x])^2  (* your objective *)
Minimize[d2, x]  (* simplest approach to minimization *)
```

[image]

Comment: Why x^(3/2.) works without constraint $x \ge 0$ (e.g. Minimize[{d2,x>=0}, x])?

Comment: @RiverLi It's the builtin behavior: only the inverse image of the reals is considered. (See the documentation, under "Possible Issues".)

Comment: @Alan yes, i understand and see what you did there. Worked like a charm. I can use this to set up other like problems. Is there a way to save code in mathematica. like if i wanted to save this to run again, without saving a whole notebook. THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: @SmallFry You can store the code in a `.wl` file and use [Get](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html), or [create a script](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/CreateWolframLanguageScripts.html).